# Go time.Now() is always 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC

Tags: datetime, time, go

I'm running Go version 1.3 on Windows 7x64. After I run the following code I always get **2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC**.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now())
}
```

I know that Go Playgroud has this fixed time for a reason, but I don't understand why I get this date in my box.

**UPDATE:**
I solved this issue by upgrading the Go version from 1.2.2 to 1.3.

Trying to reproduce the issue, I realized this had been fixed after switching the computer off and on the next day.

I recommend to restart the computer after upgrading to 1.3.

Comment: Prints the correct date for me, that's odd.

Comment: Your code is fine, looks like a windows specific bug in 1.3. A quick search in the go bugs database shows nothing about it. I'd ask in the bugs mailing list.

Comment: btw that's Go langs bday :D

Comment: t := time.Now()
fmt.Println(t.Year())
result = 2009

directly from https://play.golang.org/

Why would they do that, very annoying.

Comment: Don't know why you are disliking it. Things don't have to be serious always.

Comment: I was doing stuff on https://play.golang.org/ and it took me a while to realise the year was wrong. The date is right, but that's only because I'm running it on 10 November!

Answer (score 133):

**This is the time and date of Go Lang's birthday.**

They use this as the fixed time in the Go Tour, so perhaps you are running the tour.

Answer (score 46):

That time is the fixed time used in the Go Tour as mentioned in the [Go Tour limitations](http://tour.golang.org/welcome/4)

> In the playground the time begins at 2009-11-10 23:00:00 UTC (determining the sigificance of this date is an exercise for the reader). This makes it easier to cache programs by giving them deterministic output.

Are you sure you were not running code there?
Possibly local version - you *can* download and run the tour.

Comment: This has wasted so many developers time.
Surely they could have added a checkbox for "Use actual time" or something 

Comment: Also [significance](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2009/11/hey-ho-lets-go.html).

Answer (score 6):

I'm unable to reproduce your issue:

```
C:\gopath\src\timenow>go version
go version go1.3 windows/amd64
C:\gopath\src\timenow>go env
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=C:\go\bin
set GOCHAR=6
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\gopath
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\go
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
C:\gopath\src\timenow>type timenow.go
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println(time.Now())
}
C:\gopath\src\timenow>go run timenow.go
2014-07-02 17:33:20.3270287 -0400 EDT
C:\gopath\src\timenow>time
The current time is: 17:33:23.60
Enter the new time:
C:\gopath\src\timenow>
```

What output do you get when you run these commands?

Comment: well, trying to reproduce it in the office today, the issue seems to be fixed, possibly after shutdown